# Disable template cache globally based on condition

Tags: templating, cache, request

I'm looking for a way to disable the template cache (`{% cache %}` tags) for the entire request based on a specific condition (not just based on the current environment). In this case, the condition is a query parameter (something like `?nocache=1`), but I'm also looking for a general solution to this. There is, of course, the [`enableTemplateCaching` general config setting](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/config-settings.html#enabletemplatecaching), which I could use to toggle the template cache on and off:

```php
// config/general.php

$someCondition = true;

return [
    '*' => [
         'enableTemplateCaching' = $someCondition,
    ],
];
```

The problem is that the config is included super early during the request lifecycle, before the `Craft::$app` object is even constructed. So I can't use `Craft::$app->request->getQueryParam('nocache')` or anything else from the API. For query parameters specifically, I *could* access `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` directly, but that feels kind of dirty. And it doesn't solve the problem if I need access to anything from the API to determine whether to enable caching or not.

I've checked if there's a hook in the `TemplateCaches` service I could use, but it doesn't look like it. The other solution would be to include the condition in every `{% cache %}` tag manually, but that's error-prone and noisy.

Is there a more general solution to turning off `{% cache %}` tags based on a specific condition for the current request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of a different way to conditionally enable template caching (globally, i.e. not per `{% cache %}` tag) other than to conditionally set the `enableTemplateCaching` config setting to either `true` or `false`.

To your specific use case, I wouldn't worry about simply accessing the `$_GET` superglobal to look for that `nocache` param. This is essentially all that Craft itself does under the hood, when you use `Craft::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParams()` – except that Craft will also UTF8-encode and memoize the params, which shouldn't be critical.

So something like this should work fine:

```php
use craft\helpers\App;

$disableTemplateCaching = App::parseBooleanEnv($_GET['nocache']);

return [
    '*' => [
         'enableTemplateCaching' = !$disableTemplateCaching,
    ],
];
```

Another option is to set the config setting a bit later in the request lifecycle. For that, you can't use `config/general.php`, but will need to [create a custom module](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/module-guide.html), adding the relevant logic within an appropriate [event](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/events.html) listener (setting/overriding the config setting can be done by accessing the [Config service](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-services-config.html)).

Using the `craft\web\Application::EVENT_INIT` event seems to work nicely; the below would go into your module's `init()` method:

```php
use Craft;
use craft\helpers\App;
use craft\web\Application;
use yii\base\Event;

Event::on(
    Application::class,
    Application::EVENT_INIT,
    static function (Event $event) {
    
        // Get the "nocache" query param value
        $noCacheParamValue = Craft::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('nocache');
    
        // Make sure it's a boolean
        $disableTemplateCaching = App::parseBooleanEnv($noCacheParamValue);
    
        // Set the enableTemplateCaching config setting using the Config service
        Craft::$app->getConfig()->getGeneral()->enableTemplateCaching = !$disableTemplateCaching;
    
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response! You're right, the first approach should be alright, and using `$_GET` is indeed a bit simpler than `$_SERVER`. Though the second approach is even better, changing the config value on `init` is a great idea! Might lead to some head-scratching for other developers though, so for this approach I'll want to stick a comment in `general.php` explaining that the value might be changed by the module.